# strconv.Itoa does not accept values of type int64

Tags: go

Im learning to create REST APIs using Go. Here's where I am stuck.

> When user sends a CREATE request:

1. From the Slice of articles, I need to take the last article
2. Convert the ID(originally string) to Integer
3. Increment the Integer and convert it back to string and save it

Article Struct

```golang
type Article struct {
    Id       string  `json:"id"`
    Title    string  `json:"title"`
    Desc     string  `json:"desc"`
    Content  string  `json:"content"`
}
```

Here's the logic

```golang
// get the last id and convert it to integer and increment
    lastId, err := strconv.ParseInt(Articles[len(Articles) - 1].Id, 10, 64)
    lastId = lastId + 1 
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Internal Server Error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
    response := []Article{
        {
            Id: strconv.Itoa(lastId),//  ERROR
            Title:   articleBody.Title,
            Desc:    articleBody.Desc,
            Content: articleBody.Content,
        },
    }
```

#### ERROR

```
cannot use lastId (variable of type int64) as int value 
in argument to strconv.Itoa compiler (IncompatibleAssign)
```

Comment: @mh-cbon Itoa only returns one value: https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#Itoa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go has a strong typing system so Int32 and Int64 are not compatible type. Try to convert `lastId` into an `int` when calling Itoa:

```
    response := []Article{
        {
            Id: strconv.Itoa(int(lastId)),
            Title:   articleBody.Title,
            Desc:    articleBody.Desc,
            Content: articleBody.Content,
        },
    }
```

Edit:
As mention by @kostix in his answer, beware of overflows when converting int type (see his answer for details).
A safer solution would be something like this:

```
newId := int(lastId)
if int64(newId) != lastId {
  panic("overflows!")
}
response := []Article{
            {
                Id: strconv.Itoa(newId),
                Title:   articleBody.Title,
                Desc:    articleBody.Desc,
                Content: articleBody.Content,
            },
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The language specification [says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types):

> `uint` either 32 or 64 bits
> `int` same size as `uint`

This means, on a particular platform/version of Go `int` may be the same size as `int32`, and this is the reason why Go would not silently allow you to pass a value of type `int64` as an argument of type `int`.

Moreover, a plain type conversion `int(lastId)` suggested in another answer *should* be taken with a grain of salt: what happens when your program is compiled and `int` ends up having 32 bits in size in the compiled code, and a particular `lastId` value is outside [the number range supported by a signed 32-bit integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit_computing#Range_for_storing_integers), say, 2,147,483,648?
Again, the spec [says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

> When converting between integer types, if the value is a signed integer, it is sign extended to implicit infinite precision; otherwise it is zero extended. It is then truncated to fit in the result type's size. For example, if `v := uint16(0x10F0)`, then `uint32(int8(v)) == 0xFFFFFFF0`. The conversion always yields a valid value; there is no indication of overflow.

Hence the code

```golang
var i64 int64 = 2_147_483_648
var i32 = int32(i64)
fmt.Println(i32)
```

prints

```
-2147483648
```

And when this value is passed to `strconv.Itoa`, it returns "-2147483648" — quite possibly not what you would expect.

So, in a robust code, you ought to watch out when doing such type conversions, and either check the converted value for sanity, like in

```golang
v := int(lastId)
if int64(v) != lastId {
  panic("ouch!")
}
```

or merely use the largest convenient type via [`strconv.FormatInt`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv#FormatInt).

Comment: I updated my answer (as it was the one accepted) with your valuable point on overflows. Thx

Comment: @cylon86, well, actually in typical production code you use the type conversions like you've demonstrated quite liberally—without any additional checks. I was nitpicking more to make the OP actually think about these things in way more detail (than they are currently appear to do) ;-)